# getting data using jquery getJSON in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, getjson

i am trying to get amount of a bill through getJSON method. Though i am getting the amount, i am not able to post it. The code is as follows.

in the form

```
<div class="bill">
<%= f.collection_select :customer_bill_id, CustomerBill.all,:id,:id, {:prompt => "Select Customer bill"} %></div><br />

<div class= "due"><%= f.input :bill_due_amount, :label => "Bill Due Amt.", :input_html => { :size => 20} %> </div><br />
```

the js

```
jQuery(".bill select").bind("change", function() {
        var data = {
        customer_bill_id: jQuery(this).val()  
      }
      jQuery.getJSON(
         "/money_receipts/get_due_amount",
        data,
        function(data){
          var res = "";
      res =  parseFloat(data[0]);
      getAmount = jQuery('.due').val(res);
        });      
    });
```

and in the controller i have

```
def get_due_amount
    @due_amount = CustomerBill.find_all_by_id(params[:customer_bill_id]).map{|bill| [bill.bill_due_amount]}if params[:customer_bill_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @due_amount }
    end
  end
```

if i do `alert(res);` i do get the amount value but when i do

```
getAmount = jQuery('.due').val(res);
        alert(getAmount);
```

i get `[object Object]`

what seems to be the problem? why is the value not appearing in the form? seeking guidance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used jQuery('.due'), but this is a div element. Fou need to do the following way to set form input value,

```
jQuery('.due input').val(res);
```

It will set the amout to textbox value.