# Loading JSON data in Ruby on rails to use HIGHCHARTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, highcharts

I want to load a JSON data in RoR 4 to graphic the data using Highcharts.
I have in `index.html.erb`

```
{<h1 style="text-align:center" >HighCharts Test</h1>
<h1>Start</h1>
<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
</script>
<h1>End</h1>}
```

The `data.json` is in the same folder as `index.html.erb`.

However, it is not plotting anything when i run the code. Im very new to RoR and Highcharts. Whats the error? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a controller, let say ChartsController. and write following method in charts_controller.rb

```
def data
  # this method is to send manually json data 
  #render json: {name: 'test',data: [2,0,9,23,2,123]}
  # or read data from a data.json file, use your custom path
  data = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/views/charts/data.json")
  render json: data
end
```

and, in your view write this code.

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<h1>Start</h1>
<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
<script>  

$(document).ready(function() {
    options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.series = data;
        new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
```

```
<h1>End</h1>
```

I have tried, it works at my side, hopefully it work successfully.

Comment: Maybe it works, but I am trying to load a JSON file (30000 rows) instead of writing manually the data in the controller. The example from Highcharts 'Preprocess data using JSON' is not working for me.

Comment: I have updated answer with both options, now It will help you.

Comment: it shows now the JSON file but no plot: [
[1,12],
[2,5],
[3,18],
[4,13],
[5,7],
[6,4],
[7,9],
[8,10],
[9,15],
[10,22]
].

Comment: In case when you have many points, try to set 0 for [turbothreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold) parameter

Answer (score 1):

Haven't worked with RoR yet, but my best guess will be that either your json file should be in the `assets` folder. (or some other folder used for static files).

The other way around (the right way, I believe) will be to have a separate controller, that will render you json file after you have requested it via js code. See this question: [getting data using jquery getJSON in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274463/getting-data-using-jquery-getjson-in-ruby-on-rails)